# Is there a replacement for .load() event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I need a cross-browser (of course) way to get the native dimensions of an image file. All that I've found (e.g., [Craig Buckler](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-responsive-design-image-dimensions/), [Jack Moore](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/naturalwidth-and-naturalheight-in-ie/), and 
[Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/get-an-images-native-width/)) seem to require the image to have been loaded.

Unfortunately the `.load()` event handler of jQuery is now deprecated, but even if it weren't the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) make clear shortcomings that keep it from fulfilling my purpose:

- It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
- It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
- It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
- Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

Is there a simple replacement for `.load()`, one that doesn't have those limits? Or maybe a quick workaround? I'd rather not install a whole library or plugin, but obviously jQuery is on the table.

Comment: img.onload is very cross browser, and you can't tell how big something is until it loads. you can look for naturalHeight instead of height and wait for onload if needed...

Comment: @dandavis, thanks for your prompt reply. The same `load()` as what?

Comment: Although not tagged in your question, why not use server sider methods such as PHP's getimagesize method?

Comment: `.load()` is deprecated, but you can use `.on( "load", handler )`.

Comment: `image.onload`, and there are a million answers on how to get the dimensions of an image.

Comment: "but even if it weren't..." What are the shortcomings of these other load event handlers?

Comment: jQuery is just a library, and it used to have two `load()` methods, one that loaded content with ajax, and one that was an event handler for when something had loaded. There was nothing wrong with `load()` used for images, it was just counter intuitive to have two methods with the same name do different things, so it was wrapped in to `on()` instead, as `on('load', handler)` and all it really does is call the native javascript `element.onload = handler`, that's it, there are no advantages using one over the other.

Comment: @adeneo, thanks for your forthrightness.

Comment: *It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree*. Well, it shouldn't bubble. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/load) and [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-load)

Comment: @Oriol, I'm mostly worried about cached images failing to trigger it.

Comment: @JohnK - there's a fix for that, you check for the complete property, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is as cross browser as you'll get

```
function get_dimensions(image_element, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        callback({width: this.width, height: this.height});
    }
    img.src = image_element.src;
    if (img.complete) img.onload(); // avoids caching issues
}
```

you can call it like

```
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');

var width, height;
get_dimensions(image, function(dimensions) {
    width = dimensions.width;
    height = dimensions.height;
});
```

Comment: since the img has the same props as dimensions, why not just pass the image to the callback?

Comment: @dandavis - Yup, could do that, it was basically to show how you'd use the onload event to get the dimensions, all the wrapping stuff isn't really needed.

Comment: Cool. I'm trying to get it to work now and getting a Syntax error on line 4 ("callback"): `Unexpected token (`

Comment: @JohnK - was typing a little too fast, I actually forgot the function

Comment: Thanks, that's better. I added a couple small corrections to get it to work (waiting for moderation). But now the function as above *only* seems to give the dimensions when the image is cached. If it's newly loaded, the width and height are left undefined. Btw I'm using Chrome 32 on OSX.

Comment: I got it to work: just put my own code (to set `height` and `width` attributes of image) in place of the callback (and eliminated that argument). Thanks so much for your help!